# How to keep a c++ map data structure in shared memory?

Tags: c++, data-structures, shared-memory

I need to share a map :

```
map <string, vector< pair <string,string> > > repoMap;
```

among the parent and forked child process so that each of them is aware when
one of them adds/deletes an element in the map.

Please provide a small and quick solution with an example.

Comment: You need a shared memory allocator, and hope that your standard library implementation is good enough. Unfortunately the Standard doesn't require that shared memory actually works (e.g. it doesn't require that containers only use fancy pointers internally).

Comment: Check this [DrDoobs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/creating-stl-containers-in-shared-memory/184401639)

Comment: Use Boost.Interprocess: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

Comment: The fourth template argument of `std::map` is allocator. You need to create a custom allocator which will allocate stored objects inside your predefined shared memory.

Comment: What about C++11 multi-thread and a good mutex management? Is that a good solution?

Comment: @Biagio Festa your advice can be good but it depends on his custom needs. Can you please, write why do you prefer forking than threads ?

Comment: "Please do my work and research for me." No, mate..

Answer (score 0):

"Keeping track" is not something real in low-language programming. You can do the following:

- Make a function that checks content, that is thread safe
- Make a function that adds content and reports changes, that is thread safe
- Make a function that removes content and reports changes, that is thread safe

I'm going to give a quick solution, but then you have to learn more to make it fancier.

The key to this in C++11 is using [`std::mutex`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), which provides a lock on the map. For example:

```
std::mutex lock; //must be accessible by all threads, either being global (not the best, but will work) or put it in your class body
void addElementToMap(map<string, vector< pair <string,string> > >& myMap, string key, pair element)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
    myMap[key] = element;
    //the guard will be unlocked when destroyed
}
```

now you can use `std::thread` to call this function, by for example:

```
std::thread myThread(addElementToMap, std::ref(mapToModify), key, element);
```

You use `std::ref()` here because usually copies are supplied to threads.

It seems like you have to learn all the new facilities of C++11. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) is a good book.

Feel free to ask questions, but please do some research about this, too.

Good luck!